# Como deletar uma imagem da pasta Storage laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, upload, file-upload, image, laravel-5.2

Estou usando esse código para fazer upload de imagem esta tudo funcionando
minha duvida e na condição if para deletar a imagem antiga tenho que deixar uma imagem  default.jpg como padrão mais minhas condição if esta deletando essa imagem.
minha pergunta e como posso deixar essa imagem sempre default e continuar usando a condição para deletar alguém pode ajudar ?

```
 public function update_avatar(Request $request){

    if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $user            = Auth::user();
        $old_avatar      = $user->avatar;
        $file            = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename        = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $old_file_avatar = $old_avatar  . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image           = Image::make($file);

        $image->fit(250, 250, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });

        Storage::put($filename, (string) $image->encode());

        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();

    }

    //delete image
    if (Auth::user() !== $filename) {
        Storage::delete($old_avatar);
    }

    return redirect('profile');
}

public function getUserImage()
{
    $user        = Auth::user();
    $old_avatar  = $user->avatar;
    $file        = Storage::disk('local')->get($old_avatar);
    return Response::make($file,200,[ 'Content-Type' => $old_avatar]);


}
```

Quero deletar a imagem antiga e colocar a nova esse if já faz isso a questão e que não quero que ele sobrescreva a imagem default.jpg que e padrão no banco para todos os usuários.

```
 //delete image
if (Auth::user() !== $filename) {
    Storage::delete($old_avatar);
}
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta!

Comment: Vamos la Estou salvando minhas imagens na pasta Storage e uso o intervention Image que cria um link no banco de dados  desta pasta, dentro da minha pasta Storage tenho uma imagem como default chamada default.jpg que e carregada como padrao no banco. a questao e que quando subo a imagem de um usuario ela e substituida. a questao e que nao posso fazer isso pois ela e padrão para todos os usuario.

Answer (score -1):

use a função unlink().

Exemplo:

```php
unlink('caminho_da_imagem');
```

Comment: Oi! Podes explicar porque é que essa linha de código resolve o problema?